# Trouble reading/writing .bmp file in C

Tags: c, image-processing

My program needs to be able to read a .bmp image, write some data in it and then create another .bmp image. For a start, I began coding some stuff to read an image and the rewrite the same image in another file, but I got some problems in it.
Here's my code:

bmp.h:

```
#ifndef _BMP_H_
#define _BMP_H_


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
  uint16_t type;
  uint32_t fileSize;
  uint16_t reserved1;
  uint16_t reserved2;
  uint32_t offset;
} BMP_File_Header;

typedef struct {
  BMP_File_Header fileHeader;
  uint32_t bSize;
  int32_t width;
  int32_t height;
  uint16_t planes;
  uint16_t bitCount;
  uint32_t compression;
  uint32_t imageSize;
  int32_t xPixelsPerMeter;
  int32_t yPixelsPerMeter;
  uint32_t colorUsed;
  uint32_t importantColor;
} BMP_Info_Header;
#pragma pack(pop)

BMP_Info_Header* loadBMP(const char *filename, char *data);
void writeBMP(BMP_Info_Header *infoHeader, char *data);

#endif
```

bmp.c:

```
#include "bmp.h"


BMP_Info_Header* loadBMP(const char *file_name, char *data) {
  FILE *file;
  BMP_Info_Header *infoHeader;
  int n;

  //Open the file
  file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if (!file) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read file %s.\n", file_name);
    exit(1);
  }

  //Alloc and read the headers
  infoHeader = (BMP_Info_Header *) malloc (sizeof(BMP_Info_Header));

  n = fread(infoHeader, sizeof(BMP_Info_Header), 1, file);

  //Check format
  if (infoHeader->fileHeader.type != 0x4D42) {
    fclose(file);
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image");
    exit(1);
  }

  //-------------------------Checking the image--------------------------
  if (infoHeader->bSize != 40) {
    fclose(file);
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load image correctly");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((infoHeader->planes != 1) || (infoHeader->bitCount != 24)) {
    fclose(file);
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid image");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (infoHeader->compression != 0) {
    fclose(file);
    fprintf(stderr, "This software currently does not support compressed BMP files.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  //Move the file through the offset until the beginning of the data itself
  fseek(file, sizeof(char) * infoHeader->fileHeader.offset, SEEK_SET);

  //Allocate the char array to the needed size to hold the data
  data = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * infoHeader->imageSize);

  //Actually read the image data
  fread(data, sizeof(char), infoHeader->imageSize, file);
  printf("%s", data);

  //Verify the data
  if (!data) {
    fclose(file);
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load image data correctly\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fclose(file);
  return infoHeader;

}

void writeBMP(BMP_Info_Header *header, char *data){

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("output.bmp", "wb");
  int n;

  if (!fp) {
    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create output file\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  //-----------------------WRITE THE IMAGE------------------------
  //Header
  n = fwrite(header, sizeof(char), sizeof(BMP_Info_Header), fp);
  if (n < 1) {
    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't write the image header.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  //Offset
  fseek(fp, sizeof(char) * header->fileHeader.offset, SEEK_SET);

  //Data
  n = fwrite(data, sizeof(char), header->imageSize, fp);
  if (n < 1) {
    fclose(fp);
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't write the image data.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  fprintf(stdout, "Image written successfully!\n");
}
```

It seems to always fall off at the "Couldn't write the image data" error.  Can somebody help me? I'm fairly new to programming and couldn't fix it by myself.

Comment: Use a debugger and find out why.

Comment: You should use the bitmap headers defined in windows. h.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MichaëlRoy The headers used (`unistd.h`) suggest that the code is for *nix.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yup, I'm on a Mac

Comment: @MichaëlRoy what if your target OS isn't windows?

Comment: You correctly allocate `sizeof(char) * infoHeader->imageSize` memory, but then read `sizeof(char)` bytes into it. What exactly do you expect that to do for you? What exactly do you think `printf("%s", data);` is going to print?

Comment: @KenWhite I coded the printf to test if I was reading the data correctly.

Comment: It is not text. It might have a string terminator, but not where you expect.

Comment: You output something as a string (null-terminated) that isn't a null terminated string. That call to printf shows you nothing except random garbage up to the first null.

Comment: @KenWhite isn't the second argument of fread the size of each element to be read? This is what I expect, to get the data of the image and store it in a char array.

Comment: @felixpalmen  what if the code needs to be ported later ?  member names are important.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy the code is in general non-portable as soon as a "packed struct" is used. Member names on the other hand don't matter at all. But using `windows.h` makes it even *less* portable.

Comment: The struct is packed _because_ the bitmap header is a file header. It's specified explicitly, as it should be, to would ensure compatibility. That's a first step towards portability.  What if the user would like to reuse his code at a later date?  Should he rewrite his library in 5, or 10 years?  Is it a dumb move to leave the door open to reuse published, open source code in his library today?

Answer (score 1):

So, I did found the solution to my problem. Trouble is, when a BMP file is NOT compressed, the value in the `imageSize` variable found in the `BMP_Info_Header` struct is equal to 0, so when I called the `fread` and `fwrite` functions, they wouldn't read or write anything because the `header->imageSize` value was 0. The solution I found was to substitute the `header->imageSize` calls for `3 * header->width * header->height`, that way I can get the real image resolution and I multiply it by 3 so I can get the exact pixel values. By the way, thanks for the help guys! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is with the `fseek`, for which you don't check the return value.

```
  fwrite(header, sizeof(char), sizeof(BMP_Info_Header), fp);
  fseek(fp, sizeof(char) * header->fileHeader.offset, SEEK_SET);
  fwrite(data, sizeof(char), header->imageSize, fp);
```

See, if your current position after writing the header is less than the `fileHeader.offset,` , what do you expect to happen? Fill the remaining bytes with random values ? with zero? In any case, you should explicitly write those bytes.